# Strange behavior: Java escape euro sign

Tags: java, internationalization

With the following code:

```
    System.out.println("\"1. \u20ac\"");
    System.out.println("\"2. Euro sign \u20ac\"");
    System.out.println("\"3. Eurovalue +1,25\u20ac\"");
```

I get following results:

```
    "1. €"
    "2. Euro sign €"
    "3. Eurovalue +1,25?€"
```

Why is there a question mark '?' on row 3. just before the euro (€) sign?

Could someone explain what I am doing wrong? My environment is Windows 7 Eclipse 3.1 with Jre build 1.6.0_18-ea-b05

Comment: I don't get the question mark. How do you execute that code? I've seen a bug in Eclipse when printing UTF-8, where it occasionally produces strange results (suddenly prnting wrongly things that work 100 times before and 100 times aftewards).

Comment: It works fine on my Linux box - could you describe your exact environment? (OS, Java version etc)

Comment: Have you tried a newer version of Eclipse? 3.1 is close to 5 years old.

Comment: Have you tried running the application from the command line?

Comment: Really strange. If I put everything in its own java file and run it within Eclipse, it works!

Answer (score 3):

I think I solved it.

In Eclipse there is encoding cp1252 for the java file. It looks the same as ISO-8859-1 but at runtime the result is different. By configuring file encoding to cp1252 it works again.

Really scary :)

Answer (score 0):

I have executed the code and I got your desired output fine.
as below
"1. €"
"2. Euro sign €"
"3. Eurovalue +1,25€"

Since you are getting the wierd output it might be the language setting at your local machine locale settings,
That might help you

Comment: Strange if it is encoding because it is escaped. 
It works really strange depending on which parts I concatenate first, the result is different. If I concatenate first euro sign together with something else and then finally combine it together with a longer string, it works fine.